# Как адаптивно вставить в input иконку?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```css
.inp {
  position: relative;
}

.inp:after {
  content: '';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

```html
<div class="inp">
  <input type="text" value="" class="input input1" placeholder="Ваша почта" />
</div>
```

Пожалуйста скажите, как вставить в `input` иконку адаптивно ?

Comment: А что именно не получается? Верстка вполне рабочая... Только надо указать верные данные для положения иконки? В чем именно проблема?

Comment: @Air на различных экранах иконка которая вставлена в input выходит за пределы inputa

Comment: @Air простите дядя что так долго не отвечал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если придерживаться такой схемы ..то будет все точно

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

i.fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваша почта">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.inp {
  background: url(images/your-icon.gif) no- 
    repeat scroll 7px 7px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 }
```

Саму иконку можно поставить как фон и добавить отступ в инпуте, зависящий от ширины вашей иконки.